# How to execute multiple methods sequentially at particular amount of time using thread

Tags: java, multithreading

In Java, I have ten methods like

```java
public void getFile();
public void getEmployeeFile();
.
.
.
public void getProductFile();
```

How can I execute these methods sequentially at some particular amount of time using thread.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here. Can the question be simplified to how to run a job in background after a predetermined time? Because you don't need threads to run stuff sequentially. Just call the methods one by one.

Comment: Maybe it lost something in the translation. What do you mean by: _at some particular amount of time_ Do you mean that you want all the ten methods to complete in a certain amount of time?

Answer (score 1):

Technically, threads allow executing tasks concurrently. executing these functions in sequence is a single thread task.